# Matlab - matrix to the power of 2

Tags: matlab, matrix, exponent

In `Matlab`, I have typed the following commands:

```
>> a = [1 2; 3 4]

a =

     1     2
     3     4
```

When I tried the command `a^2`, I got the following:

```
>> a^2

ans =

     7    10
    15    22
```

I was actually expecting to get:

```
ans =

       1     4
       9     16
```

In other words, I was expecting to get each element of the matrix to be raised to *2*.

Why was the result as shown above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In MATLAB, all single-character operators are *matrix* operators. So, you are using the *matrix* power, e.g.,

```
a^2 == a*a
```

if you want to square each *element*, you'll have to use the *element-wise* power operator:

```
>> a.^2
ans = 
    1   4
    9   16
```

Read more about MATLAB's operators [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html).

Answer (score 6):

When you type `a^2` in Matlab, what you are actually executing is `a*a` (**Matrix** multiplication). If you want **element-wise** operations in Matalb, you need to type

```
a.^2
```

Note the difference between `^2` and `.^2` !
The little dot `.` before the operand marks an **element-wise** operation, as opposed to matrix operation.

The same goes for other operations, such as `/` vs `./`, `*` vs. `.*`, etc.